# Rails multiple checkbox for category selection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, checkboxlist

I have a form to create events and also i have a model for category selection

the event model is given by

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
end
```

and i have `t.belongs_to :category` in the event migration and i have `t.string :name` in the category migration

i have done this so as to select a single category for the event

but now i also want to select the multiple interest for the event and their names must be fetched from the category table so as to store the category_id in another column(interest) in the events table.

I am doing it so as to find users who belongs to the same category (i have also included category id in the user table )

please tell me how it can be done ? thanks in advance

**UPDATE 1** - actually i want to store the interest in category for the event like the event belongs to arts category and it needs to find users and other events who belongs to arts, commerce, science etc .... this is interest of the event

**UPDATE 2** - so that in its show view i can fetch the users and other events who belongs to the category which the events has in its interests

Comment: You can reach the event's category name by doing this: Event.category.name

Comment: User.where(:category_id => Event.category) is this what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Or if you want to fetch the categories, you need:
 <%= f.collection_select(:category_id, @categories, :id, :name, :include_blank => "Please select") %>

Comment: actually i want to store the interest in category for the event like the event belongs to arts category and it needs to find users and other events who belongs to arts, commerce, science etc .... this is interest of the event

Comment: i have used f.collection_select already .. for the event , this refers that this event belongs to a category 
and in the same form . i need multiple select checkboxes to store the categories the event is interested in

Comment: So you want the Event to have a category it belongs to , but also have multiple categories as interests?

Comment: yes yes .. so that in its show view i can fetch the users and other events who belongs to the category which the events has in its interests

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87702/discussion-between-codeprotocol-and-hristo-georgiev).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a little bit of a hacky workaround to do this, but it is possible:

**Model**

In your model add:

```
  class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
        serialize :interests
      
    end
```

**View**

Given that `@categories` contains all the categories, you can make checkboxes of interests like this (put this in your view for the event):

```
   <tbody>
      <% @categories.each do |category| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= check_box_tag "interests[]", category.id %></td>
      </tr>
      <% end %>
    </tbody>
```

**Controller**

When you submit the form, you will receive them in this format:

```
"interests[]"=>["3", "4", "5"]
```

You can reach those values by using `params[:event][:interests]` or `params[:interests]` , depending if the form is wrapped or not. You can check the parameters in your terminal, when you post the form.

In the first case, the results will be automatically sent to the model, but in the second case, where you have only `params[:interests]` you need to manually assign them upon creation, like this:

```
   @event.interests = params[:interests]
```

Eitherway, you are trying to get an array in a column, so you need to serialize it. That's why there's a `serialize` in the model. Additionally, you have to have your column value as a `text` (t.text) , not as a string.

In theory, each time you reach Event.interests , you will get an array which you can iterate through with `each`

Comment: what i need to write in the migration of event i have very less idea of serialize ... is it just 't.text :interests' ?

Comment: change_column :your_table, :your_column, :text if you already have it

or just add it in the migration as a text, not as a string

Comment: how will it store to that column ? have you used the column name in the form ?

Comment: my whole post is about how the data is going to be stored in the column. It needs to be passed as an array. you can see the code for the view i put out there

Comment: i added some clarifications